# How to set automattically date in one column when other column has been filled up

Tags: google-sheets

I have to columns. One has a date field and the other one a value (i.e. cost). We can call the first one column A, and the second one column B. I want to register the date when each cost has been set. That means, that when a value has been set in column B, column A must be filled up automatically with current date.

My first idea is to use `today()` but this function updates the value each time the document is opened. That means that all values of column A always has current date.

I have wondered if it is possible to use `today()` only the first time. Therefore I have tried to do something like:

```
if(AND(len(A1)=0,len(B1)>0), today(), "")
```

But still the date is updated to current date.

My second approach is to set `today()` in a cell, and try to copy the value in column A when column B is filled up. The problem is that I need to copy the content of the cell, not the formula. And I cannot use in this case `Paste special -> paste values only` due to is a manual interaction. Searching a little in google I have found [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wipIXJTZOjfXJqJM8HCf_R9StLnOu-t_yMWCCWWfIjk/edit?hl=en_US&hl=en_US#gid=0) where recommends this actions to copy value and not formula:

Data -> Validation:

1. Cell range: Sheet1!C2
2. Criteria: Items from a List
3. Create list from range ... Sheet1!E2

That is not a bad approach, but still I need to select the range in the dropdown list. It is not selected automatically. Here we have a screenshot:

[image: No default value]

There is a better approach to achieve my purpose? Or do I need to create a snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use google app script onEdit. If Column B is edited, it will fill A with the date.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet=e.source.getSheetName()
 if( sheet == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet 
  var column = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn();
   if( column == 2 ) { //checks the column
      var newCell = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().offset(0,-1);//get column A of active row
      if( newCell.getValue() === '' ){ //If A is empty?
         var d = new Date();// d is now a date object
         newCell.setValue(d)}
      else{return}
      }}
```

Comment: There is not any native action to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Not that I know of, you can create a user defined function and copy it down, but onEdit seems easier.

Comment: Your solution is easy to do. Only that I do not expect to program it myself!